# How can one debug angular 2 app on safari?

Tags: angular, debugging, safari, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

There's a feature in my app that's working fine on chrome but not so on safari, I need to debug it on safari, but unfortunately I haven't found any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Lol, it was simpler than I thought, you can just put debugger on your code and you can start debugging!
Although it's hard to navigate to a particular file in safari console, this good old method works great.